# Jest with @expo/vector-icons cause async error?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo

This is my component . I use jest to test it as simple as possible . but got the error when it go to the Ionicons component . createIconSet .

```
const HeaderBackButton = ({ navigation, color }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.buttonContainer}
      onPress={
        navigation.getParam("overrideBack") || (() => navigation.goBack())
      }
    >
      <Ionicons
        name={"ios-arrow-back"}
        size={32}
        color={color || Colors.greenSilverTree}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

I run jest test with it

```
describe("HeaderBackButton", () => {
  test("HeaderBackButton renders correctly", () => {
    const navigation = {
      getParam: () => {
        return true;
      }
    };
    const tree = renderer
      .create(<HeaderBackButton navigation={navigation} color={"#123123"} />)
      .toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

And I got this error :

```
●  Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?
    Attempted to log "The above error occurred in the <Icon> component:
        in Icon (at createIconSet.js:38)
        in Icon (at HeaderBackButton.js:14)
        in View (created by View)
        in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
        in AnimatedComponent (at TouchableOpacity.js:308)
        in TouchableOpacity (at HeaderBackButton.js:8)
        in HeaderBackButton (at HeaderBackButton.test.js:20)
```

Any ideas , pls help :(